# R - Permutations between 2 or more vectors, with constraints

Tags: r

I would like to generate all possible permutations between 2 or more vectors, but;

1. Order is important.
2. The first number must be lesser than the second, and the second must be lesser than the third.
3. There cannot be the same number.

For instance:

```
a <- c(3, 5, 8)
b <- c(8, 10, 12)
c <- c(12, 15, 20)
```

The first element is from `a`, the second from `b` and the third from `c`.
Possible results would be:

> (3, 8, 12), (3, 8, 15), (3, 8, 20), (3, 10, 12), (3, 10, 15) and (3, 10, 20).

But there shouldn't be results with repeated numbers, for instance:

> (8, 8, 12), (8, 12, 12).

How can this be accomplished using R?

Comment: A naive, inefficient method would be to do `out <- expand.grid(a=a,b=b,c=c)` and then subset the result like `out[with(out, a < b & b < c),]` I'm sure someone will be here shortly with a solution that doesn't require calculating every possibility though.

Comment: Have you tried any code in R that you can put in your question?  Or researched any solutions?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have tried. I have found a solution similar to the one above, but it takes a long time to generate all possible outcomes, as pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your rules correctly, this should work.

```
a <- c(3, 5, 8)
b <- c(8, 10, 12)
c <- c(12, 15, 20)

f <- function(x,y) lapply(y[y>tail(x,1)], function(zz) c(x,zz))
g <- function(x,y) unlist(lapply(x,f,y=y), recursive=FALSE)

do.call(rbind,g(g(a,b),c))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    3    8   12
#  [2,]    3    8   15
#  [3,]    3    8   20
#  [4,]    3   10   12
#  [5,]    3   10   15
#  [6,]    3   10   20
#  [7,]    3   12   15
#  [8,]    3   12   20
#  [9,]    5    8   12
# [10,]    5    8   15
# [11,]    5    8   20
# [12,]    5   10   12
# [13,]    5   10   15
# [14,]    5   10   20
# [15,]    5   12   15
# [16,]    5   12   20
# [17,]    8   10   12
# [18,]    8   10   15
# [19,]    8   10   20
# [20,]    8   12   15
# [21,]    8   12   20
```

For 4 vectors, you would use

```
do.call(rbind,g(g(g(a,b),c),d))
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution, but it returned the following error: Error in do.call(rbind, g(g(a, b), c)) : could not find function "g"

Comment: Really? `g` is defined on the line before.

Comment: As you are new to SO, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.